# Difference between Object Creation and Class Instantiation

Tags: design-patterns

When I was reading the definition for Creational Design Patter in Wikipedia, have come across the following sentences.

**Creational design patterns are further categorized into Object-creational patterns and Class-creational patterns. Where, Object-creational patterns deal with Object creation and Class-creational deal with Class-instantiation.**

I was under the impression that Object Creation and Class Instantiation are one and the same. Are they same or Different? If they are different what will be the differences?

Comment: I *think* by "Class instantiation", they refer to classloading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happen to visit the following linke Got the answer.

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns

**While class-creation patterns use inheritance effectively in the instantiation process, object-creation patterns use delegation effectively to get the job done.**

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, there is no difference with that. Object creation is also considered as creating instance of a class where the result is an object created. So basically they really are the same so do not get confused with it.

Answer (score 1):

As wikipedia "[Creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)" :

> Object-creational patterns defer part of its object creation
>   to another object, while Class-creational patterns defer its object
>   creation to subclasses.

And as what I understand about the object creation and class creation :

**Object creation** : It is more about control object lifetime and creation - that is why we defer object creation to another object - we need to control one of the following:

- When the object create such as in Lazy loading
- Object lifetime such as in Singleton
- Number of active objects such as in Object Pool

where as in **Class Creation** : 
We just care about how the object construct and instantiate and this almost done by sub class, such as the following:

- Abstract Factory and Factory Method we create an object of contract with different underlying behavior
- Builder we need to separate the construction of a complex object
- Prototype we create an object by copy of another

Answer (score 0):

From point of object oriented most of the times we use *object creation* and *class instantiation* interchangeably and as far as my knowledge it is true, but from point of design pattern (Creational design pattern) it more detail and specific which is defined as "[While class-creation patterns use inheritance effectively in the instantiation process, object creation patterns use delegation effectively to get the job done](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns)"